# Proper argument for malloc

Tags: c

I have always used the `malloc` function as, for exemple,

```
int size = 10000;
int *a;
a = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

I recently run into a piece of code that discards the `sizeof(int)` part, i.e.

```
int size = 10000;
int *a;
a = malloc(size);
```

This second code seems to be working fine.

My question is then, which form is correct? If the second form is, am I allocating needless space with the first form.

Comment: What does "working fine" mean? Both versions allocate some memory. Nothing wrong with that so far.

Comment: Working fine means that I can load 10000 integers in the second version.

Comment: You can't load 1000 integers into distinct positions in the second case, only `1000 / sizeof(int)` ones.

Comment: @rpsml If you're loading 10000 integers in that space, you're corrupting memory.

Comment: @self. Depends on the platform.

Comment: @self Yes that is what I expected hence the first version that I usually use. I was puzzled as why the second version worked.

Comment: But as pointed out by @xxbbcc the second version probably just corrupts memory. I am cycling the second version in a realistic code to see when the code crashes.

Comment: @rpsml You were simply lucky - if you overwrite memory that doesn't belong to you, all bets are off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument to `malloc` is the number of bytes to be allocated. If you need space for an array of `n` elements of type `T`, call `malloc(n * sizeof(T))`. `malloc` does not know about types, it only cares about bytes.

The only exception is that when you allocate space for (byte/`char`) strings, the `sizeof` can be omitted because `sizeof(char) == 1` per definition in C. Doing something like

```
int *a = malloc(10000);
a[9000] = 0;
```

may seem to work now, but actually exploits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` allocates a given number of bytes worth of memory, suitably aligned for any type. If you want to store `N` elements of type `T`, you need `N * sizeof(T)` bytes of aligned storage. Typically, `T * p = malloc(N * sizeof(T))` provides that and lets you index the elements as `p[i]` for `i` in [0, N).

Answer (score 2):

From the man page:

> The  malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

The first form is correct.

Even if the sizeof(int) on the machine you are targeting is one (which is sometimes true on 8-bit microcontrollers) you still want your code to be readable.

The reason the "second code seems to be working fine" is that you are lucky.

The version of malloc you are using might be returning a pointer to an area of memory that is larger than what you requested. No matter what is happening behind the scenes, the behavior may change if you switch to a different compiler, so you do not want to rely on it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! And +1 for referring to `man`. In fact, *all* documentation worth its storage space ought to mention this (which suggests the OP did not read any...)

Comment: `int` must be at least 16-bit if the implementation conforms to the C standard .  (This doesn't preclude `sizeof(int)` being `1` but it seems you are trying to suggest that there could be an implementation with 8-bit ints)

Comment: Which "C standard"? There are lots to choose from.
I have used proprietary C compilers that use 8-bit ints.
Not all C compilers conform to the standards.

Comment: @Jongware actually I read the documentation for malloc and, as I mentioned, I use the proper form. However, as I pointed out, I found a piece of code written by someone else and the program did not crash. So I was puzzled. The answers indicating memory misuse were helpful. The OP did not read any documentation, not that useful of an answer...

Comment: @rpsml: well then the documentation told you the first way was the only correct way to do it ;-) Don't worry, asking why it did not crash *was* a good question -- which David addressed.